# Getting the text of a clicked display group in Corona

Tags: lua, coronasdk

To simplify my problem:

1. I have the following loop:

   ```
   local arguments =
   {
       { text="foo", x=0, y=0, font=native.systemFont, size=32 },
       { text="bar", x=0, y=0, font=native.systemFont, size=32 }
   }

   for _,item in ipairs( arguments ) do
       local text = display.newText( item.text, item.x, item.y, item.font, item.size )
       text:setFillColor( 1 )  -- white
       text.x = 50 + 50 * i
       text.y = 100

       i = i + 1

       text:addEventListener( "touch", onTouch )
   end
   ```
2. The function onTouch is defined previously and it responds by allowing the user to drag the object around the screen.

The function works fine. However, I would like to be able to access the text of the object the user clicks in from within the onTouch function. For example, if a user clicks on text that contains the string "foo", I would be able to access this string and work with it. Is this possible? I am using Corona Starter (the free one) in case that is relevant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short:

Yes, it is possible you should simply declare a variable with a string on the object as such:

`text.string = "foo"`

And then in your `onTouch` function you can reach it through

`event.target.string`